# How to build a WHERE query from a comma delimited string of ids?

Tags: sql, clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I would like to be able to build one query which takes a string of uuid's and spiting it out by commas to generate the following sql statement:

uuid

```
4506ef72-aa17-452b-9456-38d11c71897b,bd46629d-0e8c-4d70-874a-76bfade8ef14,b0c11580-7cde-4a4e-ba0a-30f9de52e3b5
```

sql

```
SELECT * FROM my-table WHERE uuid="4506ef72-aa17-452b-9456-38d11c71897b" OR bd46629d-0e8c-4d70-874a-76bfade8ef14 OR b0c11580-7cde-4a4e-ba0a-30f9de52e3b5 ORDER BY created DESC;
```

I have attempted generating this query using sqlkorma in the following method, however I am having a problem generating the WHERE clause.

```
(defn fetch [uuid]
  (->
    (korma/select* :my-table)
    (korma/order :created :DESC)

    (as-> query
          (if (not= uuid nil)
            (for [id (str/split uuid #",")]
              (korma/where query {:uuid id}))
            query))
    (korma/query-only))
)
```

Comment: Which SQL dialect(s) are you working with? The Postgres solution may look very different from the Oracle solution...

Comment: I am using Postgres.

Comment: you should give Walkable a try https://github.com/walkable-server/walkable
it's a new sql library for clojure

Comment: you're lucky because you can use `IN`. For complex queries, korma can become hairy quickly.

Comment: your query, in walkable:
`
[{(:my-table {:order-by [:my-table/created :desc]
              :filters [:or {:my-table/uuid [:= "aaa"]}
                        {:my-table/uuid [:= "bbb"]}
                        {:my-table/uuid [:= "ccc"]}]})
  [:my-table/id :my-table/title :my-table/content :my-table/created]}]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
(defn fetch [uuid]
  (-> (korma/select* :my-table)
      (korma/order :created :DESC)
      (korma/where {:uuid [in (str/split uuid #",")]})
      (korma/query-only)))
```

Instead of `OR`-ing the conditions, this uses `IN`.

```
(println (korma/as-sql (fetch "x,x,x")))
SELECT "my-table".* FROM "my-table" WHERE ("my-table"."uuid" IN (?, ?, ?)) ORDER BY "my-table"."created" DESC
```